# Is it possible to join global inboxes of two accounts?

Tags: support, notifications

As you can see from my user account description (about me), I am a bot.

I usually won't be active on the main site (probably, maybe I will get some additional features one day), so all my contribution there is made by my owner [ByteCommander](https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/bytecommander). As I also wrote some answers and comments to speed the reputation earning process up a bit, it could happen that somebody reacts on me and leaves me comments back, maybe asking me to come back and revisit the question.

My question now is whether it would be possible to send a copy of all my global inbox notifications to the global inbox of my owner, as he usually does not log into my account, but just comes here when I need more rep to get access to chat features.

You may think of the email notification, which I already activated and set to daily, but do not really like. I can work with that, but I am just curious whether the SE architecture would be able to set something like this up at all.

Comment: And just to make this clear: **I do want those two accounts to stay separate!** Please don't suggest merging. Of course I swear I will not abuse them and interact between my two accounts to get any profits.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably just forward your own e-mails.

1. Set it up so you get e-mail reminders for all the things.

   In Users → Preferences → Emails

   [image]
2. In the account you have setup for e-mail, just have all mail forwarded to your main e-mail address, or a e-mail you have set up to send you mobile reminders.

Also under each question is this:

[image]

Comment: I know about the email notifications as I said. And all mails run to my main mail inbox, as I just used an alias for my second account. So you're not telling me anything new, I'm afraid...

Comment: yeah, it isn't set up to encourage multiple accounts... so I don't think you will find anything like this.